# Can MSBuild run regex on my config files?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, msbuild

MSBuild generates a configuration file for me. I would then like to replace certain strings
in the file. Is this possible?

Also, I use Visual Studio as well to build my project. Can I do the same thing from Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can.  [Here](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) is an opensource library from MSBuildTasks that has a RegEx replace task in it that can be executed when a project is built.  I use it to handle the versioning of assemblies.